# No such file or directory for manifest file and no main manifest attribute when creating jar file

Tags: java, cmd, jar, manifest.mf

I'm trying to create a simple jar program name Example.java which displaying "Hello World" to the user and the code are as follow:

```
public class Example{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

and I have my manifest file as below:

```
Manifest-Version:1.0
Main-Class:C:\training\Java\JAR\s3\Example
```

when I run this command:

> java -jar HelloWorld.jar

it returns

```
no main manifest attribute, in HelloWorld.jar
```

what is the problem here and why I cannot run the JAR file? I already look for some example but those were different from mine. Anyone care to help? Thanks!

Comment: try to run : java -cp HelloWorld.jar Main

Answer (score 0):

> Main-Class:C:\training\Java\JAR\s3\Example

The `Main-Class` header should be a fully-qualified class name:

```
Main-Class: somePackage.Example
```

or just the class name if it is in the default package (bad practice):

```
Main-Class: Example
```

---

See:

- [The Java™ Tutorials - Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

> If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry point. You provide this information with the Main-Class header in the manifest, which has the general form:
>
> ```
> Main-Class: classname
> ```
>
> The value classname is the name of the class that is your application's entry point

Comment: I already tried by putting the name class itself but it's not working also.

Comment: @DarlisaCardiff What is the structure of the JAR file?

Comment: `jar -cvf HelloWorld.jar -m Example.mf C:\training\Java\JAR\s3\Example.class`

this is my command